# Translating "Why Functional Programming Matters" into Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

For cultural and intellectual enrichment, I've decided to learn a bit of Haskell. I've been reading [Hughes' "Why Functional Programming Matters"](http://www.cs.chalmers.se/%7Erjmh/Papers/whyfp.html) and am trying to translate its code into true Haskell. I've attached some of my attempt below (for the numerical parts of the paper; the alpha-beta algorithm is even more interesting but I'd also have to write a game evaluator from scratch!).

At this point it's been more of an exercise in Haskell syntax than anything else. I've already done simple things like translate `repeat` into the native Haskell `iterate`, translate a few functions that used a lot of parentheses to function composition (making them more point-free in the process), etc.

But my code certainly works, and I wonder if it's sufficiently "Haskell-ish".  Can any experts out there give me some hints?

```hs
-- 4.1 Newton-Raphson square roots
next n x = (x + n/x)/2.0

-- -- this is "iterate::(a->a)->a->[a]"
-- repeat f a  = a : iterate f (f a)

within eps (a:b:rest) = 
  if abs(a-b) <= eps 
    then b
    else within eps (b:rest)

sqroot a0 eps n = within eps (iterate (next n) a0)

relative eps (a:b:rest) = 
  if abs(a-b) <= eps*abs(b)
    then b
    else relative eps (b:rest)

relativesqrt a0 eps n = relative eps (iterate (next n) a0)

-- 4.2 numerical differentiation

easydiff f x h = (f (x+h) - f x) / h

differentiate h0 f x = map (easydiff f x) (iterate (/2) h0)

-- diff1a h0 eps f x = within eps (differentiate h0 f x)
diff1 h0 eps f = within eps . differentiate h0 f 

elimerror n (a:b:rest) = (b*(2**n)-a)/(2**n-1) : elimerror n (b:rest)

-- need fromIntegral to make a non-integer out of the Int which comes out of round
order (a:b:c:rest) =  fromIntegral (round (logBase 2 ((a-c)/(b-c)-1)))

improve s = elimerror (order s) s 

--diff2a h0 eps f x = within eps (improve (differentiate h0 f x))
diff2 h0 eps f = within eps . improve . differentiate h0 f 

--super s = map second (iterate improve s) -- how can we make this point-free?
super :: (RealFrac t, Floating t) => [t] -> [t] 
           -- w/o this it wants to be [double]->[double]
super = map second . iterate improve

-- second (a:b:rest) = b
second = head . tail

diff3 h0 eps f = within eps . super . differentiate h0 f

-- 4.3 integration

easyintegrate f a b = (f a + f b)*(b-a)/2

-- addpair becomes (uncurry (+))

integrate f a b = integ f a b (f a) (f b) 

integ f a b fa fb = 
  (fa+fb)*(b-a)/2 : map (uncurry (+)) (zip (integ f a m fa fm) (integ f m b fm fb))
  where m = (a+b)/2 
        fm = f m 

-- test: following should be about pi
approxpi eps = within eps (improve (integrate (\x -> 4/(1+x*x)) 0 1))
superpi eps = within eps (super (integrate (\x -> 4/(1+x*x)) 0 1))

-- is there any way to keep track of the number of iterations? state monad, but seems like a lot of work...\
```

Comment: The last edit by @Juliet seems to have botched the example starting from within (inside :) within.

Comment: Yes, noticed and fixed. I've now removed "pre" since it was screwing up the text; will have to live with bad syntax coloring. 

Is this a bug???

Comment: Yes, StackOverflow's syntax highlighting sucks at Haskell. Looking at Uservoice, it seems that, as usual, `codinghorror` (Jeff Atwood) quickly closes all bug reports as "declined". Probably the only way to get this fixed would be to directly report it upstream: http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

Comment: When you are done here, it would be good if you post whatever you've done to (say) the Haskell mailing list — a Haskell version of "Why Functional Programming Matters" would be much appreciated by many!

Comment: Yes, Haskell coloring doesn't work. But actually the real problem was the "pre" tag which actually deleted some text within the code.

Comment: When using <pre>, you need still to use HTML entity references in the text, e.g., "&lt;" rather than "<".

Answer (score 11):

**4.1  Newton-Raphson square roots**

These two lines

```
sqroot a0 eps n = within eps (iterate (next n) a0)
relativesqrt a0 eps n = relative eps (iterate (next n) a0)
```

are almost identical, so you could abstract things one step further:

```
sqroot method a0 eps n = method eps (iterate (next n) a0)
relativesqrt = sqroot relative
withinsqrt   = sqroot within
```

**4.2 Numerical differentiation**

I don't see the point in having `h0` as an argument to the `differentiate` function as it's just the starting point for the `0` limiting sequence. (The same is not true for `a0` in the Newton-Rhapson case, where the starting point might matter).

I think it is equally appropriate to abstract over the rate of which this limit approaches zero:

```
differentiate rate f x = map (easydiff f x) (iterate rate 1)
```

Of course one could do both:

```
differentiate rate h0 f x = map (easydiff f x) (iterate rate h0)
```

In any case, it's a pretty arbitrary decision.

**4.2 Integration**

You can use

```
zipWith (+) (integ f a m fa fm) (integ f m b fm fb)
```

instead of

```
map (uncurry (+)) (zip (integ f a m fa fm) (integ f m b fm fb))
```

which I think is more readable.

Answer (score 4):

For `within` and `relative` I would use guarded notation:

```
within eps (a:b:rest)
  | abs(a-b)<=eps = b
  | otherwise = within eps (b:rest)
```

For `second`, you could write `!! 1`. Especially that last one is personal preference, I guess.

You should also give the type signatures.

**Edit**: If you are into obfuscation, try:

```
within :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> [a] -> a
within eps l@(_:xs) = snd. head . filter ((<= eps) . fst) $ zip zs xs
   where
    zs = zipWith (\ a b -> abs (a-b)) l xs
```

(Type checked, not tested -- and I never know if I get the filter right or if it has to be negated ;)

Answer (score 2):

Roger Costello has written a two parts summary of the John Hughes [paper](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/Papers/whyfp.html) translating the original Miranda code to Haskell. Here are [part one](http://xfront.com/Haskell/Why-Functional-Programming-Matters.pdf) and [part two](http://www.xfront.com/Haskell/Why-Functional-Programming-Matters-Part-2.pdf) of his writeup.